# How can I show a modal after certain period of time endlessly?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm am trying to fire a modal after 5 seconds if the user stay inactive, and wrote this a service for this containing this code:

```
public initScreenListen(): void {
    this.mergedObservable$ = merge(
      fromEvent(document, BanKeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN),
      fromEvent(document, BanMouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN),
      fromEvent(document, BanMouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE),
      fromEvent(document, BanMouseEvent.WHEEL),
      fromEvent(document, BanMouseEvent.CLIK),
      fromEvent(document, BanMouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE),
      fromEvent(window, BanMouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE)
    );
    this.startTimer();
  }
 public startTimer(): void {
    this.createObserable();
    console.log('subscription started');
  }

public createObserable(): void {
    this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
      this.observeable$ = this.mergedObservable$.pipe(
        switchMap((ev) => interval(1000).pipe(take(this.inactivityTime))),
        tap((value) => this.isItTimeToShowPopUp(value)),
        skipWhile((x) => {
          this.timeLapsedSinceInactivity = x;
          return x !== this.inactivityTime - 1;
        })
      );
    });
  }

public isItTimeToShowPopUp(val: number): void {
    this.timeLeftForInactive = this.inactivityTime - val;
    if (this.timeLeftForInactive <= 13) {
      this.timeLapsedSinceInactivity = this.timeLeftForInactive;
      this.ref.tick();
      console.log(this.timeLeftForInactive);
    }
  }
```

and I wrote this on the component itself:

```
public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.inactivityListenService.initScreenListen();
    const subcription = this.inactivityListenService.observeable$.subscribe(
      () => {
        subcription.unsubscribe();
        console.log('here show modal.....');
        this.inactivityListenService.initScreenListen();
      }
    );
  }
```

and it works only for the first time, after that it starts to behave messy.

Can you lend me a hand, please?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried the https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-idle/core module ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have two problems within your implementation:

- You shouldn't `unsubscribe` from the main `observable` to keep it working all the time, then there is no need to recall the `this.inactivityListenService.initScreenListen()` function again after displaying the modal.
- You should use `filter` instead of `skipWhile` within the `createObserable` function, because `skipWhile` will allow every emitted value after it gets false for the first time, but `filter` will always filter every emitted value and allow only ones that conform to the given condition.

[**skipWhile:**](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/skipWhile)

> Returns an Observable that skips all items emitted by the source Observable as long as a specified condition holds true, but emits all further source items as soon as the condition becomes false.

[**filter:**](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/filter)

> Filter items emitted by the source Observable by only emitting those that satisfy a specified predicate.

Here is parts of your code that should be changed:

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.inactivityListenService.initScreenListen();
  this.inactivityListenService.observeable$.subscribe(() => {
    // >>>>> You shouldn't unsubscribe here.
    console.log('here show modal.....');
    // >>>>> There is no need to call initScreenListen again here.
  });
}
```

```js
public createObserable(): void {
  this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
    this.observeable$ = this.mergedObservable$.pipe(
      switchMap(ev => interval(1000).pipe(take(this.inactivityTime))),
      tap(value => {
        this.isItTimeToShowPopUp(value);
      }),
      // >>>> use `filter` instead of `skipWhile`
      filter(x => {
        this.timeLapsedSinceInactivity = x;
        // >>> reflect the condition after using `filter`
        return x === this.inactivityTime - 1;
      })
    );
  });
}
```

And here is a working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ekjtq1)

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to accomplish this would be to create an observable that emits whenever there have been no "activities" after 5000ms.  The [`debounceTime`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/debouncetime) operator would work great for this:

```js
export class InactivityListenService {

  private activityTriggers$ = merge(
    fromEvent(document, 'mousemove'),
    fromEvent(document, 'keypress' ),
    fromEvent(window,   'mousemove'),
  );

  public idle$: Observable<void> = this.activityTriggers$.pipe(
    startWith(undefined),
    debounceTime(IDLE_THRESHOLD),
    mapTo(undefined)
  );

}
```

Here we merge all the `activityTriggers$` using [`merge`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/merge) as you were already.

Then we build an `idle$` observable based on `activityTriggers$` that uses `debounceTime` to prevent emissions until the specified time interval has passed since receiving an "activity" emission.

Here I used `mapTo(undefined)` since emitting the source event doesn't seem relevant (*of course this is not necessary*).

We use [`startWith`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/startwith) to provide an initial emission to "start the timer" in case the user doesn't do anything at all.

Now, you can simply subscribe to `idle$` and do your work (*display modal*).

Here's a working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-69023150-simple?file=src%2Fapp%2Finactivity-listen.service.ts&devtoolsheight=50) demo.